How to prove $\exists x (x=a)$ in intuitionistic logic
How do you prove $\exists x (x=a)$ intuitionistically, where $a$ is a constant symbol?
Classically, one has
$$ [\neg\exists x (x=a)]^1\vdash \forall x (\neg x=a) \vdash\neg a = a \vdash \bot \vdash^1 \exists x (x=a)$$
but this fails intuitionistically.
I'm confused since by the definition of the rules, one cannot simply do existential generalization only into some occurrences of some variable, i.e., one does not have
$$ a = a \vdash \exists x (x=a)$$
but only
$$ a = a \vdash \exists x (x=x)$$
Or is it maybe not provable at all intuitionistically, but this is feature not a bug because if $a$ is some arbitrary term (for example some arbitrary lambda term), it might not be defined?

The intuitionistic provability of a formula does not depend on which particular proof system you use for intuitionistic logic. But how you prove a given formula very much does depend on these details! When asking "how to prove a sentence in some logic", it is therefore good practice to post a reference to, or give a  presentation of, the proof system you want (the answer) to use.

$(\exists \text I)$ holds intuitionistically.
The correct application of the rule is: with $(x=a)$ as $\varphi$, from $\varphi[x/a]$, that is $(a=a)$, derive $\exists x \varphi$, that amounts to $\exists x (x=a)$.
